# get all the class names in a package with scala

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a package

`package one.two.three`

and in that package I have

```
public trait first
```

`public class Second` and

```
pubic class Third
```

I want to get all the classes and interface(in one.two.three) names as Strings.
heard that the best way to do it is using reflection.

can someone tell me a way to do that thing please.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that is a bit more complex task than one would thought.

For instance, you may have classes in the same package but in different locations (e.g., 2 JAR files loaded by an `UrlClassLoader` may contain a package `a.b.c`).

The best way is to use already existent tools and libraries, such as the [Reflections API](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) for instance (I'm not aware of a Scala wrapper or alternative yet). They offer a robust and well tested interface for such queries.